# Given myvector.start() and myvector.end() I want to create a read-only subset of myvector without copying the data. Is this possible, and how?

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

**Given myvector.start() and myvector.end() I want to create a read-only subset of myvector without copying the data**.

Is this possible, and how?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class T> void print_vector(const vector<T> &v) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) std::cout << v[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
```

First I create the vector.

```
    vector<double> data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    print_vector(data); // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Then I want a subset. But I think this makes a copy.

```
    // Does this make a copy or not? I don't want to make a copy.
    const vector<double> subset1(data.begin() + 3, data.end() - 3);
    print_vector(subset1); // 4 5 6 7
```

How about this approach?

```
    // Another approach. Questions:
    // - Would something like this be a good alternative if I really don't want a copy?
    // - How would the performance of this be compared to a normal STL container?
    // - Is there an existing implementation of a container that does something like this, maybe a boost class?
    class SubsetType {
    public:
        SubsetType(const vector<double>::iterator &start, const vector<double>::iterator &end) { begin_ = start; end_ = end; }

        vector<double>::iterator begin() { return begin_; }
        vector<double>::iterator end() { return end_; }

        double operator[](vector<double>::size_type i) { return *(begin_ + i); }

        vector<double>::size_type size() { return end_ - begin_; }

    private:
        vector<double>::iterator begin_, end_;
    };

    SubsetType subset2(data.begin() + 3, data.end() - 3);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < subset2.size(); ++i) std::cout << subset2[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl; // 4 5 6 7
```

Or is the solution to declare all functions like f(const vector::iterator &start, const vector::iterator &en). The STL algorithms do this, right? (but generic)

Exit

```
    std::cout << "Bye!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `SubsetType` isn't read-only, because the vector elements can be modified using the iterators. You can fix that by returning `const_iterator` instead. But you might be better off looking at Boost.Range.

Comment: [llvm::ArrayRef](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ArrayRef.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use iterators (const ones where appropriate).

If you're really allergic to passing begin/end pairs around everywhere, consider using [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/range/doc/range.html) or something similar: it lets you bundle the `[start,end)` pair into a single object.

Comment: This looks promising, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a copy follow the same idiom as the std:: algorithms library and utilize a start and end iterator.  The iterators are light weight and don't carry the cost of the copy operation.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, all containers get the `cbegin()` and `cend()` functions, which allow you to create `const_iterator`s even from a non-const container. After that, just amend your algorithm to accept a begin and end iterator, and you're done.

```
print_range(data.cbegin()+3, data.cend()-3);
```

In case you're stuck with C++03, you can use a light forwarding function that turns any object into its `const` version:

```
template<class T>
T const& as_const(T const& v){ return v; }
```

And then:

```
print_range(as_const(data).begin()+3, as_const(data).end()-3);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Or is the solution to declare all functions like f(const vector::iterator &start, const vector::iterator &en).

Yes.

> The STL algorithms do this, right? (but generic)

Yes. Do it generically as well. The standard library algorithms are a very good example to model.

Answer (score 1):

Boost Range would be close to what you intend.

Below sample shows an example that

- uses the sliced adaptor to create a subrange 'view' of a vector (without copy)
- shows that modifying the original (underlying) vector elements, results in changed data in that *view*
- Uses `make_iterator_range` to do roughly the same.

Note that the [Adaptors](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference.html) are a far more flexible abstraction than simple iterator ranges.

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace boost::adaptors;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    auto output = std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ",");

    auto&& slice = v | sliced(2, 5);

    boost::copy(slice, output); 
    std::cout << '\n';

    v[3] += 10;

    boost::copy(slice, output); 
    std::cout << '\n';

    /// Alternative without adaptors:

    auto range = boost::make_iterator_range(v.begin()+3, v.end());

    boost::copy(range, output); 
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

See it live on http://liveworkspace.org/code/5be869c15f534b6161e61c392c181f2d

Execution output:

```
2,3,4,
2,13,4,
13,4,5,6,
```

Comment: `sliced` allows modifications of the range.

Comment: Requires an extra variable, tho, and in that case, he may aswell have done `std::vector<int> const& cdata = data; print_range(cdata.begin(), cdata.end());` :/

Comment: Well, then I probably don't see what the OP is after. Adding iterator range sample for completeness